# Cannot load /admin after migrating SilverStripe install to a new server

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have just moved a silverstripe install to a new joyent smartos server. Not being familiar with Linux, this was still relatively easy.

I am new to silverstripe as well, but the team here has developed on it for years.

I have the site up and running on the new server, but have not pointed the domain to it until we can thoroughly test it. So I am accessing it from it's ip address. The site displays fine and the sub pages work as well. When I navigate to the '/admin' page, I see a silverstripe page that states the page cannot be found (not an Apache 404). I copied over the .htaccess and the _config.php from the old server, so there should be no issues.

I have done a /dev/build with no errors and I can log in through the security page, but I just cannot get the /admin to come up. I am lost after spending the whole morning surfing google to find the answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:: I installed a fresh version of silverstripe into a subdirectory on the same server. Works perfectly, so that rules out any PHP issues.

I have also tried /index.php/admin with no luck.

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: In _config.php what is Director::setBaseURL('http://my.domain.com/'); set to?

Comment: The base URL should just fix references (for example to images), but this shouldn't stop the /admin from loading at all.

Comment: Can you posted the content of your .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having this problem as well. None of the solutions I found online worked for me, but I managed to figure it out.

I had apache running as a non-standard user, and the problem turned out to be that the webserver was unable to save session data for the logins.

The solution in my case was to `chown root.myuser /var/lib/php/session`. Once done, the admin page loaded fine.

Comment: Knowing much more about SilverStripe installs then I did at the time, this was likely the problem.  I will mark as correct for future users.

Comment: @rshl I am having the same problem, could you please explain more what should i do to get the admin page? if i type my domain.com/admin, I get the homepage of my site with this url appended to it.. domain.com/Security/Login?BackURL=%2admin%2Fpages

Answer (score 1):

If /admin is not loading at all and there is no 404 error, there is a high chance of a PHP error. And that should be logged in the webserver's log file. This will depend on your operating system and probably on the Joyent environment (not familiar with that breed of cloud computing). On Debian, Ubuntu, and some more it's `/var/log/apache2/error.log` (assuming you're using Apache).

If I had to guess, I'd say the permissions of `assets/_combinedfiles/` are bad. The webserver tries to create some combined JS and CSS files there (specifically `leftandmain.js` and `cmsmain.js`) and if it fails, you might get the dreaded white page of death in /admin.

Comment: I had checked and there was no PHP error PHP.  I ended up installing SilverStripe and migrating the data.  Never found the reason.  Checked permissions as well.  Thanks.